# Game of life in C, about neighbors

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks

I have a table with dimensions N and M, given by the user.
This table is filled only with 0s and 1s. So I get something like this:

```
0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0
```

My question is, how do I count the number of 1s surrounding a single one?

I started like this:

```
int nb_neighbours_M(int **tab, int i, int j, int n, int m)
{

  int nb_neighbours = 0;`

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to have two arrays `int drow[NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS]` and `int dcol[NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS]`, that store the change in coordinates for each of a cell's neighbours.

```
// North, East, South, West
int drow[NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS] = {-1,  0, 1, 0};
int dcol[NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS] = {0, 1, 0, -1};

int row, col; // the coordinates of the cell you want to check the neighbours of
int num_neighbours = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS; i++) {
        if (tab[row + drow[i]][col + dcol[i]] == 1) {
            num_neighbours++;
        }
}
```

In the example above, I only handle 4 directions, but you could easily adapt this snippet to handle 8 directions without modifying any actual code (which is a *good thing*™).

You should probably also add bounds-checking to this, since it doesn't do any.

Comment: SO if i get it right, number of directions is the size of my table?

Comment: that can't be right, you're checking 16 positions. I think you only want to do 1 'for' with that design

Comment: @AlexiBoulon: No. NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS is basically how many neighbours (regardless of their contens) a cell has. For example, you may choose that the neighbours of a cells are only those cells located directly North, South, East or West of it, but you may also equally likely chose to also consider the cells NorthEast, or such.

Comment: @dranov : Oh ok. Yes i also want to count the ones located north-east, nort-west...

Comment: @AlexiBoulon: Then you can add the changes in position for those to the `drow[]` and `dcol[]` arrays and make sure to properly adjust the `#define` for `NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS`. For example, north-east is a change of `-1` in row and a change of `+1` in column.

Comment: For efficiency, rather than bounds checking I'd recommend including a dummy boundary row and column at each end, and excluding the dummies from the outermost loop.

Answer (score 2):

By unrolling the loop you can have something like that.

```
int count_neighbours (int **a, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
  int res = 0;

  int left   = x <= 0;
  int right  = x >= w - 1;
  int top    = y <= 0;
  int bottom = y >= h - 1; 

  if (!left && !top)     res += a[x-1][y-1];
  if (!right && !bottom) res += a[x+1][y+1];
  if (!left && !bottom)  res += a[x-1][y+1];
  if (!right && !top)    res += a[x+1][y-1];
  if (!left)             res += a[x-1][y];
  if (!right)            res += a[x+1][y];
  if (!top)              res += a[x][y-1];
  if (!bottom)           res += a[x][y+1];

  return res;
}
```

Comment: So this works for the 4 cells : top right left and bottom. But i also need to count the cells in the diagonal position

Comment: this actually works for all 8 positions and you also check for out-of-bounds (which is something you probably want in a GoL game)

Comment: I see! Thank you! And i guess res is the number of neighbors?

Comment: Yes, res is the returned number of neighbors

Comment: When i use this, my game crashes :/ I can replace (int **a, int x, int y, int w, int h) by int nb_voisins_M(int **tab, int i, int j, int n, int m) if i change the values in the code right?

Comment: @AlexiBoulon: You shall use a debugger to see *where* the code crashed.

Comment: @Kirilenko The debugger said it crashes at this line : 
if (!right && !bottom) res += a[x+1][y+1];
But when i compile i have no error

Comment: @AlexiBoulon: Try with the new version of the code (see my edit).

Comment: @Kirilenko same thing :/ maybe instead of : int left   = x == 0;
it should be int left   = x == 1 and change the if with (left && top) instead of (!left && !top) ?? ANd do the same thing for top

Comment: @AlexiBoulon: What values did you use for `w` and `h`? (NB: I've changed a bit the code)

Comment: @Kirilenko I used 5 and 5, but in this programm, the user chooses the size of the table.

Comment: Rather than bounds checking, it would be more efficient to include a dummy row and column at each end and exclude them from the outermost loop.